# Resolve $ \dfrac{m^n}{(a^n-b^n)(a^{n+1}-b^{n+1})}$ where m = a $\times b$ into partial fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

Find partial fraction of $ \dfrac{m^n}{(a^n-b^n)(a^{n+1}-b^{n+1})}$ where m = a $\times b$

$ \dfrac{m^n}{(a^n-b^n)(a^{n+1}-b^{n+1})}$ where m = a $\times b$

We can write it for partial fraction :

$\dfrac{X}{(a^n-b^n)} + \dfrac{Y}{a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}}$

$= X.a^{n+1} -Xa^{n+1} + Y.a^n - b^n Y$

= $a^m(X +3Y) -b^n(X +2Y)$

$\Rightarrow X +3Y =1 $  & $X+2Y =-1$

$\Rightarrow Y =2 $ and $X =-5$ is it right of doing such problems in this manner please suggest and guide.. thanks..